# How to render a div after we get the data from an endpoint in React & Redux & Thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a user which is loggedin and validated using JWT token and i get him through the token. My problem is how to render the div after i get him from the DB. I want to display the information of the logged in user.

```
export function getUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('/api/user').then(res => dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_PROFILE',
      data: res.data
    }));
  }
}
```

and the response is a JSON format

```
{  
 "user":{  
  "email":"someemail@gmail.com",
  "id":1,
  "username":"someusername"
 }
}
```

So after i get the Json with the logged in User, i have to render the div in order to display his credentials, just like a profile page. Instead of that i receive the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>       at ProfilePage.render (ProfilePage.js:28)

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getUser();
}

renderUser({email, username}){
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          {email} {username}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

render() {
  const { profileUpdateRequest, addFlashMessage, getUser } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          {this.props.user.map(this.renderUser)}
          <ProfileForm
            profileUpdateRequest={profileUpdateRequest}
            addFlashMessage={addFlashMessage}
            getUser={getUser}
           />
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please elaborate

Comment: @TusharKotlapure his question seems pretty clear to me :/

Comment: First check if there exist the prop name user and then use map function on it. I.e. this.props.user ? this.props.user.map() : null, also map is not returning any value in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch an action that stores your user into your Redux store. An example would like this. Since Axios uses promises, you need to do something with the then clause of your Promise/get request.

```
export function getUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('/api/user').then(res => dispatch(storeUser(res)))
  }
}
```

Later on, you'll need to map your dispatch methods to your components properties. You should read this to do so: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

Secondly, you can use a quick type check in your render method if you need to.

```
{(this.props.user && this.props.user.map(this.renderUser)) || ""}
```

It's not pretty but it gets the job done.

Comment: I added a dispatch. I didnt understand exactly what the storeUser does

Comment: @Nickbo it's a contrived action. Your reducers should know what to do with your actions. I suggest reading the redux docs on [reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) and [actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)